# Custom AuthorizationHandler not being invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

I'm working with Identity for the first time. I'm following along with Microsoft's [Policy-based authorization tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0), but when I add a policy and requirement, the handler for that requirement is never called. In fact, it acts like the handler is never retrieved from DI (if I comment out the line adding the handler to the DI container, the app's execution doesn't change at all).

The `NotLoggedInHandler` is meant to ensure that certain pages are only accessed by users who aren't logged in. The handler just succeeds and returns, so the requirement should always pass:

```
public class NotLoggedInHandler : AuthorizationHandler<NotLoggedInRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, NotLoggedInRequirement requirement)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

But when I access a protected Razor Page, I get this in my log output:

`[xx:xx:xx INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met: WebApp.Policies.NotLoggedInRequirement`

I've fiddled with the order of adding services. It doesn't seem to matter whether `NotLoggedInHandler` is registered before or after `services.AddAuthorization`.

My `Startup.cs` file looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    // Other methods/ctor omitted

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Identity services omitted

        // Set up Authentication
        services.AddAuthentication(...);

        // Set up Authorization
        services.AddAuthorization(
            options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(
                    "RequireAnonymous",
                    policy =>
                    {
                        policy.Requirements.Add(new NotLoggedInRequirement());
                    }
                );
            }
        );
            
        services.AddTransient<AuthorizationHandler<NotLoggedInRequirement>, NotLoggedInHandler>();

        // Other services omitted, not related to Identity/auth
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I was making assumptions and just needed a step back. As detailed in the [tutorial from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0#handler-registration), handlers are registered against the `IAuthorizationHandler` interface.

The tutorial shows how to **create** a handler for a single requirement and a handler for multiple requirements, but only explicitly shows how to **register** a handler for multiple requirements. It wasn't explicitly stated in the tutorial that the process is identical, and based on my experience with ASP.NET's DI container, I thought my solution made sense (because a one-to-one handler implements `IAuthorizationHandler<TRequirement>`, but a one-to-many handler implements `IAuthorizationHandler`).

However, it is the same regardless. I'm not sure how ASP.NET resolves these dependencies since any number of handlers will be registered to the `IAuthorizationHandler` interface, but it works regardless.

Changing this:

`services.AddTransient<AuthorizationHandler<NotLoggedInRequirement>, NotLoggedInHandler>();`

to this:

`services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, NotLoggedInHandler>();`

effectively solved the problem.